# C++ usage extern in front of function

Tags: c++

I have seen an interview question from Bloomberg from here: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=383154

```
extern void print(int *a, int z);
void print(int *a, int z);
```

Question 1> Will it compile?

Question 2> If it compiles, what does it mean?

```
extern int i;
int i;
```

Question 3> Will it compile?

Question 4> If it compiles, what does it mean?

Comment: What exactly is YOUR question?

Comment: It seems that I have to ask the same question back to you:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// a function declaration
extern void print(int *a, int z);
// still a function declaration
void print(int *a, int z);
```

*Answer 1*

Yes, it compiles successfully.

*Answer 2*

A global function without a body `{}` is automatically a function declaration. The keyword `extern` is optional. So both of them are just declarations. And multiple declarations are just fine.

```
// a variable declaration
extern int i;
// a variable definition without an initializer
int i;
```

*Answer 3*

Yes, it compiles successfully.

*Answer 4*

One is a declaration and the other is definition. Note that this definition doesn't have an initializer though. For global variables, you need explicitly add keyword `extern` to distinguish a declaration with a definition. And it's perfectly conform to [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) in C++.

**Edit**: I cannot open the link there. I assume the code you mentioned is in a global context.

Comment: -1 Answer 1 is incorrect. Answer 3 is also incorrect. Whether the code compiles depends on context. An absolute answer "yes" holds only for a different question, namely whether it can be made to compile.

Comment: Given the context, It's fine to assume they're in a global context.

Comment: @Erik, see my answer for an example where the code for Q1 does not compile.

Comment: @Erik, no, I would not say it's fine to assume in particular context. The OP is not stating any such context. There is no "default context" in C++.

Comment: @Alf, Erik is not me:)  ok, I updated my answer to involve the context I assume.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1** refers to this code:

```
extern void print(int *a, int z);
void print(int *a, int z);
```

Whether it will compile depends on where it's placed. For example, at the outermost level within a class definition it will not compile.

```
struct X
{
    extern void print(int *a, int z);   // invalid storage class for a class member by vs2010
    void print(int *a, int z);
};

int main()
{}
```

**Q2**. `extern` specifies extern linkage, which says the definition can be in another translation unit. This is the default for functions. Your C++ textbook should discuss use of `extern` and `static`.

**Q3** refers to this code:

```
extern int i;
int i;
```

Whether it will compile again depends on the context, where it's placed.

**Q4**. If it compiles then it's declaring an extern linkage variable `i`, and defining that variable (it can't be an automatic local variable that's defined because that would be a redefinition of the name `i` in a way that's not supported by C++).

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

extern in declaration will allocate the memory needed in this compillation unit, and during linking there will be a definition. in a nushell.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case it would compile successfully. Here is the link you can refer to[Ideone sample test](http://ideone.com/ySDBL). Since both the cases you are only declaring the functions, it is ok to declare the entities multiple times as long as there is only one definition.

The same rule applies for the second one as well.